# Setting AWS on-demand instances using Terraform aws_spot_fleet_request resource using a launch_template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.12.x

I created a launch template using Terraforms [aws_launch_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template) resource. I then use the created template to create an AWS spot fleet using the [aws_spot_fleet_request](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_fleet_request) resource. Straight-forward enough.

In the AWS console, I can also launch spot fleets using launch templates, and there I have the option to create on-demand instances, as seen in this screen shot

[image]

However, I don't see how to do the same using the `aws_spot_fleet_request` resouce. So though I successfully create the spot fleet, I don't see any on-demand instances created, they're all spot instances. What's the trick to add on-demand instances to my fleet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws_spot_fleet_request` **does not support** spot fleets with spot and on-demand instances. Thus, `aws_spot_fleet_request` is for a spot fleet containing only spot instance.

However, there is already a **PR made** to add this functionality:

- [r/spot_fleet_request - on demand arguments](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/13127)

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Such a shame it's missing that functionality so I can't use it.

Comment: PR Merged some time ago!
So you can now use this functionality ;)